# Isn't iterator a built-in function, why do I have to import it?

Tags: java, eclipse, iterator

```
// inside my class 
public void playRound() {
        Iterator<Player> itr = players.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
             Player player =itr.next();
             player.play(par);
        }
        // Supply this code!
    }
```

It says :**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Iterator cannot be resolved to a type**

Isn't Iterator a built in function?

I am forced to import :

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

If I want to resolve this issue, is there a way to avoid importing the Iterator.
The reason why I cannot simply import the Iterator even though it would save me a lot of time, is because for my project I am not allowed to import anything other than **import java.util.ArrayList;**

Furthermore, I am using eclipse to write my code.

Comment: `Iterator` is a class. You need to import every class you use either directly or indirectly

Comment: *I am not allowed to import anything other than import java.util.ArrayList;* - then maybe don't use Iterator?

Comment: You can say java.util.Iterator<Player> but I guess this is not the goal of the exercise. It looks like the teacher or the one providing the snippet forgot to import it, doesn't seem to be part of the code you have to provide.

Comment: Whats the reason for all those downvotes?

Comment: @MarcusPólo some might think she didn't put enough effort in it... java programers tend to judge people more harshly than for example sql where the same questions are answered over and over again, only the table names are changing ;-)

Comment: I suspect the assignment wants you to loop over the indices rather than using an iterator.  (Or you could use a for-each loop which just uses the iterator implicitly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word - no. There's nothing "magical" about an `Iterator`. It's a class from the `java.util` package, and if you want to use it you should either import it or reference its fully qualified name:

```
java.util.Iterator<Player> itr = players.iterator();
```

But I guess this is also forbidden by your requirements. Instead, you could just use an enhanced `for` loop:

```
for (Player player : players) {
    player.play(par);
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @yshavit noted in the comments, since `players` is a `List` and not just any old `Iterable`, you can access elements directly via their index, meaning you could also use an "old fashioned" `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); ++i) {
    players.get(i).play(par);
}
```

Comment: Or a non-enhanced `for` that iterates over the indices. With what's given in the question, it's hard to know which one the teacher wants.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterator use:

```
    // inside my class 
    public void playRound() {
        for (Player player : players) {
               player.play(par);
        }
        // Supply this code!
    }
```

It's the same thing, just without the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Iterator` is built into JDK (since version 1.2), but you need to explicitly import it, the reason is only `java.lang` package classes are by default imported, not the other packages i.e., because `Iterator` class is from `java.util` package you need to explicitly `import` it.

Answer (score 0):

It is built in the Java's main library. Not the java itself.

In Java, every class has to be imported or referenced in order to use. It doesn't matter if it is built in or not.

Your options are:

1. Do not use iterators. Use the arraylist instead for it.

> ```
> // inside my class 
> public void playRound() {
>         ArrayList<Player> itr = new ArrayList<Player>();
>         while(itr.listIterator().hasNext()){
>              Player player =itr.listIterator().next();
>              player.play(par);
>         }
>         // Supply this code!
>     }
> ```

2. Your other option is to reference it directly instead of importing.

> ```
> // inside my class 
> public void playRound() {
>         java.util.Iterator<Player> itr = layers.iterator();;
>         while(itr.hasNext()){
>              Player player =itr.next();
>              player.play(par);
>         }
>         // Supply this code!
>     }
> ```

I would recommend the first option since the second one might still be considered an import.

Comment: Your solutions make sense. However I am slightly confused about what you mean actually with 'It is built in the Java's main library. Not the java itself.'?

Comment: Java is a language. Does not include any class. It includes the primitive types only.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly import classes in `java.lang`.  You can use `String`, `StringBuilder`, `Exception`, etc., without `import` statements.

Comment: No imports are necessary because StringBuilder and StringBuffer are both in the java.lang package. They probably just assume that every code would import it. (I really like this question, well done)

Comment: The first loop won't work. Each iteration, you create a new iterator and see if it has an element. If it does, you create yet another iterator and fetch its first element. Then the next time, you create a new iterator again -- and remember, each iterator starts from the beginning. If the ArrayList isn't empty, this will spin forever, adding the first element over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be clear that **Iterator** is NOT a *class* !
Even some of the respondents here have got this wrong.

It is an *interface* - which is a set of methods that may be used by objects from a number of different classes. The classes associable with **Iterator** are naturally classes that hold groups of objects.

As you know, we must always insert some class into the angle brackets after the keyword **Iterator** when declaring one. This makes available all the methods of this interface. The basic way of declaring an **Iterator** for some array or collection class is to call the *iterator()* method for that connected class. You could also instantiate your own **Iterator** via code like:

```
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList{"Billy", "Mickey", "Jimmy", "Sam"});

. . . 
. . . 

Iterator<Player> myIter = new Iterator<>()
{
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Player next()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

};
```

But as you see, this forces you to implement the 2 abstract methods *hasNext()* and *next()* belonging to the **Iterator** interface and this is effectively rewriting the same code that is already written within the collection class: collection classes always implement the **Iterable** interface and thus can call the *iterator()* method to generate the iteration sequence. So it's simpler to declare an **Iterator** via a code line like:

```
Iterator<Player> playerIter = players.iterator();
```

Secondly, you can't use Iterator without importing its library, *java.util.Iterator*, into your project. But since your project forbids use of any library other than *java.util.ArrayList*, you can't use **Iterator** here.

You must simply use the indices of the **ArrayList** to advance through the items.
The only built-in classes and interfaces in *java.lang* library are listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/package-summary.html).